# ember-cp-validation not executed everytime dependent keys changed

Tags: ember.js, ember-cp-validations

Let me share the problem I stumbled upon longer ago and fixed today.

### Problem description:

Validator not executed everytime dependent keys changed.

My custom validator checking uniqueness of custom-meta **keys** is defined as follows:

```
import BaseValidator from 'ember-cp-validations/validators/base';
import Ember from 'ember';
const {isEqual} = Ember;

export default BaseValidator.extend({

  /**
   * Validates custom-metas of the {spot} model.
   * The validation leans upon duplicates detection of the 'key' property values.
   * @example:
   * spot.set('customMeta', [{key: 'duplicate'}, {key: 'duplicate'}]);
   * spot.get('validations.attrs.customMeta.isValid') -> false
   * spot.set('customMeta', [{key: 'unique 1'}, {key: 'unique 2'}]);
   * spot.get('validations.attrs.customMeta.isValid') -> true
   * ...skipping rest of the doc...
   */
  validate(value, options, spot) {

    const customMetaKeys = spot.get('customMeta').mapBy('key');

    if(isEqual(customMetaKeys.get('length'), customMetaKeys.uniq().get('length'))){
      return true;
    }

    return this.createErrorMessage('unique-custom-meta-keys', value, options);
  }

});
```

The validator was executed exactly **twice** although the dependent keys have changed more often. I thought the problem could come from [model-fragments](https://github.com/lytics/ember-data-model-fragments) addon or observer that was fired on the same conditions which was related to other feature.

This was my validation declaration:

```
const Validations = buildValidations({
  customMeta: {
    description: 'Custom-metas',
    validators: [
      validator('unique-custom-meta-key', {
        dependentKeys: ['customMeta.@each.key'],
        debounce: 500
      })
    ]
  }
});
```

and model definition:

```
export default Model.extend(Validations, {
  customMeta : fragmentArray('custom-meta')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

After looking into [ember-cp-validation](https://github.com/offirgolan/ember-cp-validations/blob/c5739fd02272daec7b7b63a34d92ce4fa3eb515a/tests/integration/validations/factory-dependent-keys-test.js#L268) code I noticed a difference in declaring a validator that depends on multiple values from the collection:

```
dependentKeys: ['model.friends.@each.name']
```

As you can see, the `model` property in the dependent keys declaration did the trick. Nowadays also their [online doc](http://offirgolan.github.io/ember-cp-validations/docs/modules/Common%20Options.html#dependentkeys) provide a correct declaration which wasn't the case back then when I stumbled upon the problem for the first time.

```
dependentKeys: ['model.customMeta.@each.key'],
```

Very stupid mistake, but maybe this thread saves someone's day ;-)